# Unable to connect from Google Cloud to Bitbucket repository using app password

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm using GCP build triggers connected to Bitbucket repositories. The connection is made using user credentials. Bitbucket has announced they're ending support for account password usage:

> Beginning March 1, 2022, Bitbucket users will no longer be able to use
> their Atlassian account password when using Basic authentication with
> the Bitbucket API or Git over HTTPS. For security reasons, we require
> all users to use [Bitbucket app passwords](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/app-passwords/).

Problem is, when trying to connect to a repository in GCP, the only option to supply Bitbucket credentials is via a web login (which to the point of app passwords, you cannot login via the bitbucket.org with an app password).

[GCP Bitbucket login prompt via bitbucket.org](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6Ix7.png)

Expected behavior: GCP provides an option to submit app password credentials when connecting to a Bitbucket repository.

Comment: Have you tried following [this walkthrough](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/automating-builds/build-repos-from-bitbucket-cloud) to use SSH keys for authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed [directions for GCP Cloud Build](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/automating-builds/build-repos-from-bitbucket-cloud) integration with Bitbucket Cloud and successfully built out a functioning trigger for my [repository here](https://bitbucket.org/simaslennikov/gcp-build-trigger-poc/src/master/). I only built the trigger in GCP and used the generated webhook URL when creating the webhook in Bitbucket: I didn't create SSH keys, nor is my `cloudbuild.yaml` entirely valid - so the builds are failing.

Access to the Bitbucket repository was provided through GCP GUI in Cloud Build.

Comment: Thank you! Using SSH instead of the built-in basic auth works.

Answer (score 0):

I have been informed of this change as well. I am trying to understand the scope of the change and its impact. It states that you cannot log in Atlassian account and password. However, besides using app passwords, you can also log in using OAuth2. https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/bitbucket/oauth-2/

In the case of GCP Build Triggers, when I first set up the Bitbucket repository to connect to, I need to go through the "Authorization Code Grant" flow and acknowledge what access I am granting to Google Cloud Source Repository.  If you check the Bitbucket API endpoints being called, they are URLs that are being used for "Authorization Code Grant" flow.

Based on these findings, am I right to say that there is no necessity to change existing triggers or mirrored repositories on GCP since they are using OAuth2 in the first place instead of Atlassian accounts and passwords?

Comment: Good question. I don't recall ever seeing "Authorization Code Grant" in my setup (see my linked screenshot above, it's just straight oauth with basic auth credentials). So perhaps this was all a false alarm, but I won't be able to verify as I've since switched to SSH and webhooks per above response. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you can setup the build trigger to be done by a webhook you can configure the build with ssh key. But if you have to configure it as a manual trigger then using the bitbucket login credentials is the only option. Personally, I don't like this config with user login though.

The only good thing is even now(after bitbucket stopped supporting the login credentials for code checkout) the code checkout in GCP is working fine.