# Mirror repository from BitBucket Cloud to Google Cloud Repository for App Password changes

Tags: google-cloud-platform, bitbucket, google-cloud-repository

with the upcoming changes as outlined in

https://bitbucket.org/blog/deprecating-atlassian-account-password-for-git-and-bitbucket-api-activity

How does it affect mirroring a Bitbucket Repository to Google Cloud Repository? I noticed that in the instructions in Google https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/mirroring-a-bitbucket-repository , the credentials used during logging in to Bitbucket are the account email and password, not the username and app password.

Does anyone have an idea whether things will break and what changes are required to get mirroring working?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to connect from Google Cloud to Bitbucket repository using app password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70807901/unable-to-connect-from-google-cloud-to-bitbucket-repository-using-app-password)

Comment: Hi @Sergiusz 

In the case of GCP Cloud Source Repository/Build Triggers, when I first connect to the Bitbucket repository, I need to go through the "Authorization Code Grant" flow. If you check the Bitbucket API endpoints being called, they are URLs that are being used for "Authorization Code Grant" flow.

Based on these findings, am I right to say that there is no necessity to change existing triggers or mirrored repositories on GCP since they are using OAuth2 in the first place instead of Atlassian accounts and passwords?

Answer (score 1):

According to Atlassian this change will only affect channels that are utilizing account password:

> Bitbucket users will no longer be able to use their Atlassian account password to interact with Bitbucket via Git over https and the Bitbucket API

App passwords are currently not working when mirroring Bitbucket in GCP. You can either contact their [support](https://support.atlassian.com/contact/#/) or wait for them to contact you:

> We'll be contacting teams and users based on what we find in our logs for Atlassian account password usage.

Comment: Hi @Sergiusz

App passwords are not currently working in GCP Cloud Source Repository but I believe it is also the case that Atlassian account passwords are not being used. What is being used is OAuth2 "Authorization Code Grant" flow.

Comment: Perhaps. What I meant is that the initial authorization as described here [1](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/mirroring-a-bitbucket-repository#create_a_mirrored_repository) does not accept app password.